# Change color of circle in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, drawable

I have a LinearLayout like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/powerCircle"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20sp" />
```

Then I have a background of a colored circle, like this:

circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#666666"/>

    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

In my custom `adapter`  I want to change the background color of the circle based on a status variable.

How do I get a reference to the `circle's` background?

Comment: how many different states are you dealing with ?

Comment: About 5 different colors.

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm unable to check it right now but I find mentions that `View.getBackground()` actually returns `GradientDrawable`

Comment: @Blackbelt `View.getBackground()` returns `Drawable`, but `<Shape>` is a [pointer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) to `GradientDrawable`

Comment: Yeah actually it does work, I had a typo.  I did not even need a gradient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this should work:

```
GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) linearView.getBackground();
background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```